# Where is the Tibetan Book of the Dead online in Tibetan script?

Tags: reference-request, tibetan-buddhism, books

[THLib](http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/k-2-1-1) contains the Kangyur and Tengyur in Tibetan script, which is a lot of text. But it doesn't seem to contain the Tibetan Book of the Dead :(

Is there any place online that has the Tibetan Book of the Dead in text format?

Searching Google for བར་དོ་ཐོས་གྲོལ reveals [this](http://www.khabdha.org/?p=5189) and [this](http://www.buddism.ru:4000/?field=1&index=5149&ocrData=read), but I can't tell if that is it. Or perhaps [this](http://dharmacloud.tsadra.org/tib/%E0%BD%91%E0%BD%BA%E0%BD%96%E0%BC%8B/%E0%BD%96%E0%BD%A2%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%91%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A0%E0%BD%B2%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%90%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A6%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%82%E0%BE%B2%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A3%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%86%E0%BD%BA%E0%BD%93%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%98-2/)?

Answer (score 2):

The Bardo Thodol isn't in the Kangyur or Tengyur, it's a terma text, so in a different classification. You can get the text from [here](https://dharmacloud.tsadra.org/book/%E0%BD%96%E0%BD%A2%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%91%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A0%E0%BD%B2%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%90%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A6%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%82%E0%BE%B2%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%A3%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%86%E0%BD%BA%E0%BD%93%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%98-2/) in Tibetan, or [here](https://www.dzongkha.gov.bt/uploads/files/publications/BARDO_THEDOL_CHENMO_2be8de98a37dc2142dcf5b8d6229aa24.pdf) in Dzongkha.